# How to find all (possibly relative) urls on a website?

Tags: html, regex, url, web-scraping, w3c

As a programming exercise, I'm crafting a small python tool to download a whole website locally. To be able to browse the website locally, I need to translate all URLs to relative URLs. Otherwise, resources files (.js, .css) would be downloaded from the original website instead of using the locally downloaded version. And since I need to rewrite URLs, I figured I can also change the files hierarchy. This leads to this slightly more general question:

**How can I find all URLs in a website?** A regex based on `http://domain.tld/path` won't cut it because an `href` attribute might contain a relative URL.

So far, I have identified the followings:

**HTML**

- `href=<url>` (quoted)
- `src=<url>` (quoted)
- `srcset=<list>`
- `action=<url>` (quoted)
- `background=<url>` (quoted)

**CSS**

- `url('<url>')` or `url(<url>)` (can be quoted or not)
- `@import(<url>)`

**JS**

- for JS I don't think a perfect solution exist. Using a regex to look for full URLs seems like the only way (e.g. `http://example.tld/path`)

[EDIT] See also [this post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/if-you-like-regular-expressions-so-much-why-dont-you-marry-them/) for some regexes to find urls. Incomplete as `srcset` is not used there.

Comment: `^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

Comment: `<a href="//example.com/index.html">link</a>` @Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a good start ?

```
mech-dump --links 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313765
```

Retrieve:

- mailto
- http(s) links
- images

This command is installed with the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) module: [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize)

Package `libwww-mechanize-perl` for Debian based distros